# Jenkins- Run a batch file when no jobs are running currently

Tags: jenkins

I need to kill the child process started by maven after the completion of the job. I tried `Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.enabled=true` but it does not kill all the `java.exe` processes after the job is completed. So I created a batch file to kill those processes.

The problem is, I have to make sure that no job is currently in progress before executing this batch file in Jenkins. Is there a way to achieve this requirement?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Exclusive Execution Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusive+Execution+Plugin) might be exactly what you need.

From its documentation:

> When this option is enabled, then for every build one pre-build and one post-build steps are executed:
>
> **pre-build steps:**
>
> - The plugin will initiate a shutdown mode which means that no other jobs can be started.
> - It waits until every job except this one has finished, unless it is indicated not to wait through optional flag.
> - Then it starts to execute the job.
>
> **post-build steps (executed always even if the build is not succesful):**
>
> - Jenkins shutdown mode is canceled

**Edit:** You then can put your kill-task in a separate job with the exclusive execution enabled, and launch it as a post-build action.

Comment: @Domiinik Gebhart, thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I opted for after searching. It works